Facing Angular resolver error after fixing "Cannot Get" problem
Not a long ago I've deployed my project. Only after deploying I realized that I have this "Cannot GET" problem when refreshing my page:
Cannot GET / on page refresh with express
I've fixed it by copying the answer to that question:
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist', 'index.html'));
});

But after adding that to my code, it created a new issue:
When I try to enter the page that is using Angular Resolver, I'm getting this error in the console:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): X_: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"https://tacheles-7fbc518a6a19.herokuapp.com/api/arguments", "ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure during parsing for https://tacheles-7fbc518a6a19.herokuapp.com/api/arguments"}

This is the get request from the backend file I made the changes that solved the "Cannot GET" problem:
app.get('/api/arguments', (req, res) => {
    Argument.find({
    }).then((arguments) => {
        res.send(arguments);
    });
})

This is (part of) my app-routing.module.ts
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'dictionary', component: DictionaryComponent },
  { path: 'arguments', component: ArgumentsComponent, resolve: { arguments: ArgumentsResolverService} },

(All paths are working except the 'arguments' one)
arguments-resolver.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { Argument } from 'src/app/models/argument.model';
import { TachlesService } from 'src/app/tachles.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ArgumentsResolverService implements Resolve<Argument> {

  constructor(private tachlesService: TachlesService) { }

  resolve(): 
  Observable<any> | Promise<any> | Argument {
    return this.tachlesService.getArguments();
  }
}

Even when I commented the use of the Resolver in the arguments.component.ts file, I still got the same error, so I figured there's no need to copy that file as well.
Any ideas? Thanks!

please share the full server.ts

Your resover return implements Resolve<Argument>, but must implements Resolve<Argument[]>

@NarenMurali i don't have a server.ts in my project.
maybe this >>> will help?
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const { mongoose } = require('./db/mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { User, Argument,Temp, Term } = require('./db/models');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
});

@librogil The file that contains app.get('/api/arguments', (req, res) => {     Argument.find({     }).then((arguments) => {         res.send(arguments);     }); }) I want to know the order of the routes.

@NarenMurali thanks for trying to help :) pasting a code here looks bad, so i uploaded a scrennshot of the file (deleted some other get/post commands so it'll fit): https://ibb.co/J2bW5Mv

@SergeyChe i tried your answer, but it didn't change anything...

@librogil try defining the arguments route above the app.get('*' part

@NarenMurali GENIUS! how did you come up with that? thank you so so much!

@NarenMurali did that :) i guess i should edit my question as well. it's not really about the resolver in particular, just basic backend (the other pages that continued to work didn't use a backend...). thanks again!

@librogil no problem, thank you!

The routes are match from top to bottom, so your wildcard route is matching before the arguments route, hence the problem.
The solution is to promote the argument route (and all node api routes) above the default HTML wildcard route.
app.get('/api/arguments', (req, res) => {
    Argument.find({
    }).then((arguments) => {
        res.send(arguments);
    });
})
...

...
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist', 'index.html'));
});

